# deploying a grails war file to a Tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, grails, groovy

I wrote a `Grails` application, everything works fine, then I generated the `myapp.war` file to be deployed in a `Tomcat 6.0` server running in a VM. I generated the `.war` file with

```
grails war
```

Then I moved the file to the `/tomcat/webapp` location on my server, and it was expended into the directory `myapp`.
However, when I try to access the application, I get:

```
Message:    
FAIL - Application at context path /myapp could not be started
```

I'm new at deploying `.war` files into Tomcat servers. I was testing my application within my `SpringSource` IDE, as `localhost:8080/myapp` and everything is working fine, however, when I try to deploy that to `<my-server>:8080/myapp` I'm getting that error message.
Any is that happening? Could someone please help me with that error?

Comment: Check logs and provide more info

Comment: Maybe your grails.serverURL wasn't set right in Config.groovy? It has to be set to the URL of your production server (including the context path) in the production environment. By default, Grails packages WARs in the production environment.

Comment: @ArtHanzel I will post more details tonight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the log files in Tomcat. Carefully examine every row to check for fatal errors. It could be a single row in the log file that makes Tomcat refuse to start the application.

I have had several cases where a small "innocent" row in the log file was the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, the log files that are being referenced are located under %TOMCAT_HOME%/logs.

Another alternative is to use the Tomcat Manager. Here is a good link on how to get started. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html

Either way, when you click on the deploy button (Image attached), it will give you an error if something critical has occurred with the deployment of your war. It is certainly not as detaled as the catalina logs, or the stdio logs, but it might be easier to troubleshoot, let alone, you do not have to manually keep transferring the file.

[image]